# Transfer rate using a USB 3.0 to USB-C adapter

Tags: usb-3, usb-c

I have an external SSD drive that connects via USB 3.0. If I use a USB 3.0 to USB-C adapter would I be able to take advantage of the faster USB-C speeds or would the transfer speed still be only as fast as what USB 3.0 would give me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your speed will be at USB 3.0 speeds.

#### When negotiating between slower and faster protocols, the transfer will only be as fast as the slowest side of the connection.

While USB C connections have the potential of reaching speeds of 5Gbps to 10Gbps when using USB 3.1 Gen 1 and Gen 2 connections, if you are connecting via USB 3.0 there is no guarantee you will reach speeds like that simply because you are connecting a USB 3.0 devices with a USB C adapter.

That said, USB 3.0 devices *might* be able to reach 5Gbps if it is a USB 3.0 SuperSpeed (SS) device. But it is not guaranteed.

For example, I had a Seagate Backup Plus 4TB USB 3.0 that I connected to the USB C port on my MacBook Air and the speed honestly wasn’t 5Gbps all time. I was able to improve the speed of the drive by removing it from the standard Seagate Backup Plus enclosure and putting it in a new USB C specific enclosure. Now I consistently get solid 5Gbps transfer speeds from that device.

Past any USB protocol specifics, speed between digital devices needs to be mutually assured on both sides of a connection.

- **Phone Modems**: A 300 baud modem connecting to a 1200 baud connection will only ever be 300 baud.
- **Ethernet**: An 10Mbps ethernet connection connecting to a 100Mbps device will only ever be a 10Mbps ethernet connection.
- And so on… And so on…

That said there *might* be improved USB 3.0 speeds depending on the device because newer devices tend to use newer/faster components. As I explain [in my answer to this other SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/a/883649/167207), I saw a very clear improvement in speed when I connected external USB 2.0 hard drives to the USB 3.0 connection on a Mac mini.

So in the end nothing is guaranteed as far as actually speed of a slower protocol goes, but no matter what speed you get it will never be faster than the slowest side of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a USB 3.0 (5Gbps, Gen1) device to Type-C port won't give you the Gen2 (10Gbps) rate, this should be obvious. The USB3.0 device will send "capability message" as Gen1 device, and the Type-C host will switch into Gen1 mode even if it might be Gen2 capable.

However, Gen2-class controllers usually have higher bandwidth on the side between USB (xHCI) controller and PC host data fabric/memory, and usually have some other enhancement to DMA tranfers (like prefetch). So the host-contorller overhead will be less, and your device might have slightly more efficient bus utilization and therefore slightly improved performance (likely only on some specific benchmark-style workloads), which you might be unable to notice in reality.